# How to pass Authorization header via apolllo client to use in graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

In my react app I am trying to send an authorization header with each graphql query/mutation I make.

I can see the header in my request as the following picture shows:

[image]

but I get a 401 as response.
when I run the same request in postman (with the authorization header) it works and I receive the data as response.

Here is my apollo client setup:

```
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';
import {ApolloProvider} from 'react-apollo';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context';

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {

// get the authentication token from redux store.
  const token = store.getState().loginData.jwt;
  // add the jwt token to the authorization header.
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
    }
  }
});
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: process.env.GRAPHQL_API_URL,
  credentials: 'same-origin' 
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  ssrMode: true,
  connectToDevTools: true,
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink)
});
```

There aren`t any errors in console.
the response headers are :

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the console logs, if there is any error? Also show us the response headers